# How can I run kdb+tick end of day at time other than midnight

Tags: kdb

I want to run .u.end at 5pm NY time.

Alternatives being considered:

- Set Machine TZ to Europe/Helsinki - which makes Midnight = 5pm NY Time.
- Set Machine TZ to UTC - and run at 22:00
- Set Machine TZ to NY and run at 17:00  <  this would be nice

I can't find how to run u.end at non-midnight time.

What are implications to consider?

Has anyone had experience doing this they want to share?

Answer (score 7):

You would have to modify `tick.q` to meet your new condition. You can see the code here:

https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick/blob/master/tick.q

... that `ts` function which is called by the timer simply checks if `.u.d` is smaller than `.z.d`. Change that if condition, maybe by doing something like `.z.p > .u.d+17:00`. (although of course you need to update the last time you instigate the .u.end so that this condition doesn't get continually met on the same day :) )

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set a timer.

First define following function:

```
        q) .z.ts:{ if (current time=5 PM) then call .u.end }
```

Then set a timer frequency. For ex. following line will call '.z.ts' every 2 sec.

```
        q) \t 2000
```

Reference: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zts-timer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a vanilla kdb+tick setup, where:

- 5010 is the ticker plant
- 5011 is the realtime database (RDB)
- 5012 is the historical database (HDB)

Connect to ticker plant and call function `.u.endofday` with zero arguments.

```
q)h:hopen 5010 / ticker plant
q)h".u.endofday[]"
q)hclose h
q)h:hopen 5011 / RDB
q)h"" / wait for RDB to complete last async request
q)hclose h
```

The above commands could be automated with a shell script + UNIX cron.

Comment: Its a good solution, but would auto increment `.u.d` which isn't necessarily what is required.